# How can I update dates in a cursor in FoxPro?

Tags: visual-foxpro

I am trying to compare a date defined by the user with a date I have in a table and count 7 days at a time until the dates match. Basically, it’s counting weeks, but how can I get it update the date in the cursor?

```
Set Date BRITISH

users_year = Year(users_date) && users_date is a public variable in week1get.scx

Select * From "t:wiptrack\routecard\week1" Where;
    year = users_year Into Cursor ben
Select ben
Goto Top
my_date = ben.firstmon

*count up to week
X = 0
Do While users_date >= my_date
    my_date.DATE() + 7  && Trying to add 7 days to date
    X = X + 1
    If X >= 100
        Messagebox("Count is greater than 100")
    Endif

    Loop

Enddo
```

Comment: Re "fox pro": Do you mean [***Visual*** FoxPro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_FoxPro)?

Answer (score 3):

You have to store the new value somewhere after you compute it. In addition, the DATE() function doesn't do what you think. Assuming the my_date variable contains a date, you do this:

```
my_date = my_date + 7
```

Comment: Thank you I'm so stupid I had initially done that and commented it out as when I ran it it gave me unknown variable when checking it against my code I had goofed and wrote ``` my_date = mydate + 7````

Comment: Being a beginner doesn't make you stupid. It means you're ignorant, but you're working on curing that. Good luck in your learning. Don't hesitate to ask more questions.

Comment: @TamarE.Granor I am sure that the spirit of your comment is kind and meant encouraging. It can however be read differently, please be more careful with your phrasings. And thanks for helping here.

Comment: I'd hope that in context, anyone could see that I meant the OP (who elsewhere, I believe, identified himself as a beginner with VFP) doesn't yet know much about VFP, but is actively taking steps to learn. In context, too, I hope people see that it was a direct response to the OP's "I'm so stupid." But yes, I'll be more careful.